# How do I make post url on desktop site redirect to their corresponding post url on the mobile site when viewed with a mobile device and vice versa

Tags: url, blogger, blogspot

I am using blogger to create a separate desktop and mobile site so as to provide a different experience on each site. The problem is redirecting the various post url to their corresponding url on the other site so it auto redirects when viewed on mobile devices or desktop.

E.g: www.domain.com/2018/07/christmas-shopping.html

when viewed on a mobile site to auto redirect to

m.domain.com/2018/07/christmas-shopping.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in blogger because your link already have mobile extension ?m=1.

You can only use subdomain to a new sites but this is not what you want.